# CRTP - Counting Individual Classes and Total Count

Tags: c++, crtp

I've recently learned about CRTP and have been practicing some of the better documented code examples out there to understand it better. Currently the block of code I have is able to count the instances of different derived classes but what if I want to find the total of all instances regardless of class? Here is the code I have:

```
template <typename CountedType>
class countable {
    static unsigned count_;
public:
    countable() { ++count_; }
    countable(countable const&) { ++count_; }
    ~countable() { --count_; }

    static unsigned n_alive() { return count_; }

};
template <typename CountedType>
unsigned countable<CountedType>::count_ = 0;

template <typename CharT>
class BasicMyString : public basic_string < CharT >, public countable<BasicMyString<CharT>> { };


typedef BasicMyString<char> MyString;
typedef BasicMyString<wchar_t> WMyString;

template <typename T>
class MyVector : public vector<T>, public countable<MyVector<T>> {};

int main() {
    MyString s1, s2;
    WMyString wms;
    MyVector<double> v;

    cout << "Number of MyString: " << MyString::n_alive() << endl;
    cout << "Number of WMyString: " << WMyString::n_alive() << endl;
    cout << "Number of MyVector: " << MyVector<double>::n_alive() << endl;
   //cout << "Total number of objects: " << countable::n_alive() << endl;
}
```

The last line that is currently commented out is the way I want to be able to call to see how many total objects there currently are. I know I can find the total out another way by creating a global counter and creating a new function within the class to return that global count but I want to be able to call it like this, without defining a templated argument. Do I have to make an Adapter sort of interface or is there an easier way of implementing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Make `countable` a derived class of a non-template class, such as `countable_base`, and move all the counting code to the base class.

Comment: If you do that, `countable` becomes useless, doesn't it?

Comment: Awesome, @RSahu if you want to make that as an answer I'll go ahead and accept that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Make `countable` a derived class of a non-template class, such as `countable_base`, and move all the counting code to the base class.

```
class countable_base {
    static unsigned count_;
public:
    countable_base() { ++count_; }
    countable_base(countable_base const&) { ++count_; }
    ~countable_base() { --count_; }

    static unsigned n_alive() { return count_; }

};
unsigned countable_base::count_ = 0;

template <typename CountedType>
class countable : public countable_base {};
```

**Solution 2**

Make `countable` a regular class.

```
class countable {
    static unsigned count_;
public:
    countable() { ++count_; }
    countable(countable const&) { ++count_; }
    ~countable() { --count_; }

    static unsigned n_alive() { return count_; }

};
unsigned countable::count_ = 0;
```

Comment: As state, OP loose the count by type.

Answer (score 1):

You may create an extra class to do the count which will be the base of your current template `countable` class, something like:

```
class countable_total {
    static unsigned count_;
protected:
    countable_total() { ++count_; }
    countable_total(countable_total const&) { ++count_; }
    ~countable_total() { --count_; }
public:
    static unsigned n_alive() { return count_; }
};

template <typename CountedType>
class countable : public countable_total {
    static unsigned count_;
public:
    countable() { ++count_; }
    countable(countable const&) { ++count_; }
    ~countable() { --count_; }

    static unsigned n_alive() { return count_; }
};

template <typename CountedType>
unsigned countable<CountedType>::count_ = 0;

// in cpp
unsigned countable_total::count_ = 0;
```