# Which design pattern is appropriate for countable objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, 2d-games

I have a problem that I can't solve again. As junior developer that have recently got acquainted with design patterns and doesn't deal with them yet, I need your help to find appropriate.

The issue is:

> 1. I want to generalize objects with help of an abstract class or interface.
> 2. I want to count every instance of derived class, because I need to limit their number.

For example in "Sea Battle" game I use classes: SeaObject ----> Mine, Boat, Kreyser. The quantity of mines,boats,etc  are  limited

I have tried to use static field 'count' in base class and I don't understand how to use it in the right way in derived. Because all that I could just copy and paste the static fields again. I suspect that it is not good :[.

I agree that my decision to use abstract class SeaObject is not quite right. If the better choice exists I would use it.

*Please, don't be strict to me, I am a newcomer here.
Thank you for any help.*

Comment: You may look at [counting-individual-classes-and-total-count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066469/crtp-counting-individual-classes-and-total-count)

Comment: Do you have an array/list of these `SeaObjects`?

Comment: If you put all your instances in a container (`std::vector`), then you have the size directly.

Comment: You could use a Factory pattern and keep the counting logic in the factory. The only problem with this is if you instantiate the classes directly, the factory will not be able to detect it.

Comment: @Jarod42 It would be nice; however, Java generics don't provide a static for each specialized instance, it's just one static overall.  However, I suppose it could be modified, to use a static map, with a hash of the derived class type used as a key for each individual count.

Comment: @Serge: OP tags with C++ **and** Java :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 I apologize, I completely missed that.  In C++, CRTP is my absolute favorite solution for it (and other fun things).  Still unfortunate that Java can't exactly do it the same, though.

Comment: Do you want to count the total number of `SeaObject`s or the total numbers of each, `Mine`s, `Boat`s, etc?

Comment: @Serge I am sorry, I didn't know this difference between c++ and java. In this way c++ tag may be unnecessary now because I use java.

Comment: @Walter, yes. I want to count exactly Mines, Boats, etc.

Comment: @weston, i didn't have them. I have tried to count them by static field, that is incremented with the call of the constructor.

Comment: You must have some reference to them or you can't do anything with them, like draw them, or otherwise interact. Time to show some code, like what do you do when you add a new mine for example?

Comment: @weston,the examplary diagram here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154849/which-design-pattern-is-appropriate-for-sea-battle-game-objects]. But I didn't show it here because I didn't want to mislead anyone  with it.

Comment: Move count from SeaObject class to Field class. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out object pool pattern. It's basically a factory which keeps count of the things it creates.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a reference to these objects somewhere or you cannot use them. In Java if you have no reference to an object it will just be garbage collected, in c++ it causes a memory leak.

I also see no value in a `SeaObject` knowing how many other `SeaObject`s there are so that it can limit it's own creation. Other code should make that decision.

So in your game class, you should have a list of the objects. That way it is easy to see how many there are currently and you will need it to interact with or draw these objects:

```
public class Game {
   private static final int MINE_LIMIT = 10;

   private final ArrayList<Mine> mines = new ArrayList<Mine>();

   public void addNewMineIfNotTooManyAlready() {
     if(mines.size() < MINE_LIMIT) {
        mines.add(new Mine());
     }
   }
}
```

The list `mines` could be a list of a super type like `SeaObject` if you wish/require.